# Mongo DB with C# Driver sort after project

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

We are planning to move from MS SQL to Mongo DB, but we are hesitating because of the issue we are currently encountering.

Here's the code for the projection:

```
ProjectionDefinition<PrimaryCustomerIndividual, SearchResponse> projectionDefinition = Builders<PrimaryCustomerIndividual>.Projection.Expression(
                            a => new SearchResponse()
                            {
                                AdditionalContacts = "",
                                Adviser = a.Adviser,
                                ClientSince = a.ClientSince,
                                ClientNextActivityId = a.Activities.First().ActivityId,
                                CreateDate = a.CreateDateTime,
                                CustomerId = a.CustomerID,
                                Email = a.Email,
                                LastNote = a.Notes.First().Notes,
                                LeadOrigin = a.LeadOrigin,
                                LeadType = a.LeadType,
                                Mobile = a.Mobile,
                                Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                                NextReview = a.NextReview,
                                PhysicalAddress = a.PhysicalAddress,
                                UserNextActivityId = 0,
                            }
                        );
```

With the code above we are returning a different object from our collection object, Our collection object is **PrimaryCustomerIndividual** and we are returning **SearchResponse** we did this because there are fields that was needed to be populated by other collections. We have thousands of data and we are planning to have a pagination which will return 100 records per page but right now I'm having problem on how to accurately get the first 100 and then the second 100 if there's a sort.

and here is the code on how we are retrieving the data from the database:

```
var filter = Builders<PrimaryCustomerIndividual>.Filter.Where(a => a.IsActive);
var customers = customerCollection.Find(filter).Project(projectionDefinition).ToEnumerable()
```

I'm curios if there's a way to sort the data by the field of **SearchResponse** instead of fields of **PrimaryCustomerIndiviual** after the projection definition without converting it to list first?

Comment: You can use OrderBy.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for answering sir, is there a way on doing that before converting to enumerable/list? what i mean is like ***customerCollection.Find(filter).Project(projectionDefinition).Sort(<field from searchresponse instead of primarycustomerindividual>).ToEnumerable()***

Comment: See : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: @jdweng I actually tried it but it seems like it only sorts for the collection object instead of the projected object

Comment: Do you need a aggregate?  : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/